# PHP Parse XML file for all .mp3 links

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to write a PHP script that parses an XML file for all .mp3's on https://feeds.transistor.fm/the-good-news-podcast and then echos them. I have started with PHP's simplexml_load_file(). The mp3's are located like so:

```
<enclosure url="https://media.transistor.fm/025fe5da.mp3" length="3636030" type="audio/mpeg"/>
```

How would I target all of the enclosure tag urls? Here is what I have so far but it is not working:

```
<?php
    $mysongs = simplexml_load_file('https://feeds.transistor.fm/the-good-news-podcast');
    foreach ($mysongs as $songinfo):
        $title=$songinfo->enclosure(url);
        echo $title;
    endforeach; 
?>
```

also tried this but no luck:

```
<?php
$html= simplexml_load_file('https://feeds.transistor.fm/the-good-news-podcast');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('enclosure') as $tag) {
        if(strpos($tag->getAttribute('url'),'.mp3')!==false)
        {
            echo $tag->getAttribute('url')."<br>";
        }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out thanks to [Get enclosure img url from rss feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930692/get-enclosure-img-url-from-rss-feed):

```
<?php
$rss=simplexml_load_file('https://feeds.transistor.fm/the-good-news-podcast');
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    if (isset($item->enclosure)) {
        echo $item->enclosure['url'].'<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something simple if that is where it is applied.

```
$html= simplexml_load_file('https://feeds.transistor.fm/the-good-news-podcast');
preg_match_all("/h.*mp3/", $html, $mp3s);
foreach ($mp3s as $mp3){
echo $mp3.'<br>';
}
```

this will output

```
array(1
0   =>  array(9
0   =>  https://media.transistor.fm/0cf8f8b1.mp3
1   =>  https://media.transistor.fm/f45a0d7d.mp3
2   =>  https://media.transistor.fm/2ba746c9.mp3
3   =>  https://media.transistor.fm/025fe5da.mp3
4   =>  https://media.transistor.fm/58cf9a08.mp3
5   =>  https://media.transistor.fm/65a6df2b.mp3
6   =>  https://media.transistor.fm/33e65d6c.mp3
7   =>  https://media.transistor.fm/e29ea8d3.mp3
8   =>  https://media.transistor.fm/3422d3aa.mp3
)
)
```